# Cannot use "open with" but double click works

Tags: c++, debugging, error-handling, runtime-error

I have got a tool to read data from a file and calculate optimal routings with it.

Now the program take an argument so I can just double-click the file and the program will start.

Debugging works all fine but if i try it through the "open with" dialog I get a "Debug Assertion Failed" error message at line 55 in "vctools\crt\crtw32\stdio\fprintf.c" with Expression (str!=NULL).

Is there anyone with an idea what could be the problem or what I could look for.
I can't look through call stack because when debugging I don't get any errors and when I click retry the program exits.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *but if i try it through the "open with" dialog I get a "Debug Assertion Failed"* -- At that point, without closing the dialog, use the debugger to attach to the process, hit "Break All" and look at the call stack.

Comment: thanks i got it will now see if i can solve the problem